# Is there a way to pass command line arguments to spec/rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests

Trying to pass some arguments to `rspec`, but coulnd't find any proper command-line options for the purpose. I *could* use environment variable for that, but not sure it is the best (and most transparent) way to configure the tests.

So, how can I pass the command-line arguments? If can't - which is the best and most acceptable alternative?

Comment: I think it's impossible - http://groups.google.com/group/rspec/browse_thread/thread/aa06395242dd7aae/c1ae10d2ad4dc33a?lnk=raot&pli=1

Comment: seen it - so, what's the best way to do it? environment variables? how can they be tracked than? should I wrap `rspec` with a shell script that receives an argument and pushes it to the environment variable? sounds wrong, huh. there should be a way (I think) or there must be a reason that such a functionality does not exists on purpose.

Comment: Instead of asking "how do I pass command-line arguments to RSpec?", it might be worth telling us why you want to do that, and then we can help you see if there is a better way. Needing to pass arbitrary command-line options to a program smacks of poor design.

Comment: I hear you, Bob :) My task is to perform a set of verifications for a given list of URLs. Now, the list of URLs is the parameter I would like to pass to the test (for example, the name of the file that contains those URLs). The URLs can be grouped by various parameters: quick set (just an acceptance test), full set, production set, development set etc etc etc. Any ideas on this concrete issue, please?

Comment: why not just set this URL in your tests? Does it change often?

Comment: Do you mean to hard-code the URL? Then yes, it might change often.

Answer (score 2):

One clean way to do this is to add tags for your options, though this might not work in your case.

```
rspec --tag sleep_5_seconds
```

And then in your spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  before(:each, :sleep_5_seconds => true) do
    setup_5_second_sleep
  end
end
```

This code hasn't been run, but that's the concept. You could also do it with an around block if you need to setup and teardown based on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I used [double-dashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean) for this. The example code below may not be idiomatic (I'm new to Ruby), but worked well enough for my use case of passing in directories for the spec to verify.

```rb
dirs = ARGV.dup
dirs.shift until dirs.first == "--"
dirs.shift
dirs.each do |dir|
  describe "#{dir} does the thing I want..." do
    # verify dir here
  end
end
```

Invoked as `bundle exec rspec . -- [dir1] [dir2...]`